# Can the front USB-C port on an Intel NUC 10th Gen support a display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, adapter, thunderbolt, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC BXNUC10I7FNHN 10th Gen Core i7, and I'm trying to get three monitors operational simultaneously, each with their own display (not mirrored).

The monitors are currently as below:

**1st Monitor**: HDMI Plugged into HDMI port on back of NUC.

**2nd Monitor**: HDMI Plugged into [Thunderbolt3 -> 2x HDMI adapter](https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/consumer/thunderbolt-3-to-dual-hdmi-active) (Thunderbolt side of adapter plugged into Thunderbolt port on back of NUC.)

**3rd Monitor**: HDMI Plugged into [Thunderbolt3 -> 2x HDMI adapter](https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/consumer/thunderbolt-3-to-dual-hdmi-active)

Unfortunately the NUC will only display two monitors at a time. If I unplug monitor 2, then monitor 3 comes online. If I then plug monitor 2 back in, it does not come online until I unplug monitor 3.

I notice that there's a USB-C port on the front of the NUC, could this be used for a display, thus circumventing the need for the Thunderbolt adapter?

*Things I've tried*

**1.** Updating firmware and drivers: NUC GPU, Chipset, and Thunderbolt

**2.** Setting primary & secondary displays in BIOS (no option for tertiary display)

**3.** Starting NUC with adapter plugged in (and without adapter plugged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how it's responding I'd guess it might only support 2 concurrent screens. Do you have another USB-C to HDMI or other  adapter to try on the front (second) USB-C port?
Your listed model I can't quickly find it exactly, but this similar model SEEMS to imply it supports 3. However it's got a mark that at the bottom says it might be different depending on manufacturer?
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/214598/intel-nuc-10-performance-kit-nuc10i7fnhn/specifications.html

**--EDIT**

[PDF page 26 (marked page 4) of datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005545/intel-nuc.html)

offers insight. It seems to imply you need a 'Display Port' hub or two daisy-chained monitors both of which I don't have much more clarification on. It does mention back USB-C port is the only Thunderbolt combined one. PDF pg 20 (marked page 6) Block Diagram imply DP (DisplayPort) is only on the rear USB-C port. This I can only assume your Thunderbolt adapter/splitter is not a compatible 'DisplayPort hub' & suggest looking at another one. Wouldn't hurt to try that one on the front USB-C port to see if it works it all...per schematic it shouldn't

Comment: I just tried plugging the third monitor into the front USB-C port using a VGA -> USB-C adapter (only adapter on hand currently), and unfortunately the NUC doesn't recognize it as a display, even after unplugging the 2nd monitor & Thunderbolt adapter entirely.

I tried plugging this new adapter into the Thunderbolt port, and the display showed up within a few seconds.

I think you're correct in that this model doesn't actually support 3 displays. Thanks for your help regardless. I'll (optimistically) keep the question open for a day and close it off tomorrow.

Comment: Datasheet of thunderbolt adapter you linked indicated they have a different adapter that outputs DisplayPort connectors so maybe it can't do multiple HDMI. Meaning maybe the other adapter, then using DisplayPort cables to a monitor with DisplayPort connectors could yield 3x screens. Feel free to upvote my answer if it helped. Accept if you believes it addresses your concern plz

Comment: Much appreciated - Looks like I'll need to switch to using Display Ports instead. Can't upvote as not enough rep, but marking answer as solution. Thanks again